# Websockets Group Chat to Specific Users

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, chat

I have a running chat application in my website. It is implemented using websockets, php and is working fine. The problem is whenever i send a message to single user it broadcasts that message to all users currently connected to my website. It will be really helpful if someone can tell me how to get the unique id of each user when someone connects to our app. If i can get the userid of the current logged in chat user that would solve my problem but i am unable to retrieve that userid when the user connects (open state of websocket). I can get the userid when the connection is made but I need the userid before the connection happens.  When the connecation occurs it assigns its own ids to the connected users in a serial manner(1,2,3..,n).

```
<?php
// prevent the server from timing out
set_time_limit(0);

// include the web sockets server script (the server is started at the far bottom of this file)
require 'class.PHPWebSocket.php';

// when a client sends data to the server
function wsOnMessage($clientID, $message, $messageLength, $binary) {
global $Server;
$ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

// check if message length is 0
if ($messageLength == 0) {
    $Server->wsClose($clientID);
    return;
}

//Send the message to everyone but the person who said it
foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
    if ( $id != $clientID )
        $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) said "$message"");
}

// when a client connects
function wsOnOpen($clientID)
{
global $Server;
$ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

$Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has connected." );

//Send a join notice to everyone but the person who joined
foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
    if ( $id != $clientID )
        $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has joined the room.");
}

// when a client closes or lost connection
function wsOnClose($clientID, $status) {
global $Server;
$ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

$Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has disconnected." );

//Send a user left notice to everyone in the room
foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
    $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has left the room.");
}

// start the server
$Server = new PHPWebSocket();
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');
// for other computers to connect, you will probably need to change this to your LAN IP or external IP,
// alternatively use: gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
$Server->wsStartServer('127.0.0.1', 9300);

?>
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
<style>
    input, textarea {border:1px solid #CCC;margin:0px;padding:0px}

    #body {max-width:800px;margin:auto}
    #log {width:100%;height:400px}
    #message {width:100%;line-height:20px}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="fancywebsocket.js"></script>
<script>
    var Server;

    function log( text ) {
        $log = $('#log');
        //Add text to log
        $log.append(($log.val()?"n":'')+text);
        //Autoscroll
        $log[0].scrollTop = $log[0].scrollHeight - $log[0].clientHeight;
    }

    function send( text ) {
        Server.send( 'message', text );
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        log('Connecting...');
        Server = new FancyWebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:9300');

        $('#message').keypress(function(e) {
            if ( e.keyCode == 13 && this.value ) {
                log( 'You: ' + this.value );
                send( this.value );
                $(this).val('');
            }
        });

        //Let the user know we're connected
        Server.bind('open', function() {
            log( "Connected." );
        });

        //OH NOES! Disconnection occurred.
        Server.bind('close', function( data ) {
            log( "Disconnected." );
        });

        //Log any messages sent from server
        Server.bind('message', function( payload ) {
            log( payload );
        });

        Server.connect();
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='body'>
    <textarea id='log' name='log' readonly='readonly'></textarea><br/>
    <input type='text' id='message' name='message' />
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a `temp_users` array in the server.
2. When each client connects, create a unique ID and add both the new socket and the unique ID to this array, then send the ID to the client, with a header indicating that this is a system message.
3. In the client code, have the client retrieve the unique ID from the system message. Compose a message with the unique ID and the client's username, then send it back to server.
4. Map the received username to corresponding ID in `temp_users` array. You can now identify a specific user and send them a message using the socket mapped to their username.